# add counter to column by occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the followings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value":[1,4,2,1,2,1,2,2],'type':['S','C','L','C','C','S','L','S']})

    Value   type
0   1        S
1   4        C
2   2        L
3   1        C
4   2        C
5   1        S
6   2        L
7   2        S
```

and I wish to add a counter on every time there S in type and STOP at L such that the result would be:

```
    Value   type    exit_value
0   1          S    1
1   4          C    1
2   2          L    1
3   1          C    
4   2          C    
5   1          S    2
6   2          L    2
7   2          S    3
```

I have tried cumsum with where

```
df['exit_value'] = np.where(df['type'].eq('S'),1,0).cumsum()
```

but the result 'overflow' the L

```
    Value   type    exit_value
0   1          S    1
1   4          C    1
2   2          L    1
3   1          C    1
4   2          C    1
5   1          S    2
6   2          L    2
7   2          S    3
```

Comment: Can you have multiple S or multiple L in a single group or can we guarantee that there will always be an S followed by an L? Said another way, are (`S S C L`) or (`L S C S`) or (`S L C L`) possible groups?

Comment: (S S C L), (L S C S) , (S L C L) are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming groups always have `S` succeeded by `L` we can create groups with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) as done above, filter out all values [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) not `S` or`L` then go back through and [`groupby bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) to back propagate the last valid value from L:

```
# Create Groups Starting with S
g = df['type'].eq('S').cumsum()
# Clear non S/L values and backfill within groups
df['exit_value'] = g.where(df['type'].isin(['S', 'L'])).groupby(g).bfill()
```

`df`:

```
   Value type  exit_value
0      1    S         1.0
1      4    C         1.0
2      2    L         1.0
3      1    C         NaN
4      2    C         NaN
5      1    S         2.0
6      2    L         2.0
7      2    S         3.0
```